# Joining objects glitch/bug/artifacts

Tags: modeling, modifiers, blend-files, origin

I was modeling these flowers and I wanted to join the selected parts of each flower, so I can use them as a particle system. When I selected all parts and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> I get these strange artifacts. You can see them on the second flower in the picture. All modifiers are applied. I do not know what the Problem is.

[image]

[image: in wireframemode you can also can see these strange lines]

Here is the blend-file:
[image]

Comment: maybe the last object selected (the active one) has a modifier?

Comment: It had. But I applied the subdivision and I still had the same problem.

Comment: could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: sure [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=zmGWvpvk" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/zmGWvpvk/)

Comment: I do have the problem with all of them

Comment: it works fine here with 2.8 or 2.9  :/

Comment: Ok, interesting. I don't really have a graphicscard in my pc. Maybe blender just has problems to show it correctly. In renderedmode it looks fine. Thank you very much already!

Comment: What is the name of this particular part (shown as picture above) in your file? (many flowers... so)

Comment: I actually do have the problem with all flowers